# Angular google maps. Access maps default functions

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

im working on a google map thing where i need to access the setZoom method when clicking on a custom button. The problem is that setZoom() gets undefined. I have loaded all dependencies(the map renders and my $scope.zoom runs). I have tested that. Anyone knows how to do?

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MapController">
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
    <ui-gmap-map-control template="../pages/partials/map-controls.html" controller="MapController" position="RIGHT_BOTTOM">
    </ui-gmap-map-control>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

js:

```
    $scope.map = { 
        center: { 
            latitude: 67.855800, 
            longitude: 20.225282 
        }, 
        zoom: 13,
        options: { 
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
        }
    };
    $scope.zoom = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        //the problem is here.  $scope.map.setZoom() gets undefined.
        $scope.map.setZoom(9);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call

```
$scope.map.control.getGMap().setZoom(9);
```

instead of

```
$scope.map.setZoom(9);
```

See the example controller for more info - https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/cbd17a3a225dfe543faa124eb295e66db566f27c/example/assets/scripts/controllers/example.js

--- updating example

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MapController">
<ui-gmap-google-map 
     center="map.center" 
     zoom="map.zoom"          
     options="map.options"
     control="map.control>
    <ui-gmap-map-control 
     template="../pages/partials/map-controls.html" 
     controller="MapController" 
     position="RIGHT_BOTTOM">
    </ui-gmap-map-control>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

js:

```
scope.map = { 
        center: { 
            latitude: 67.855800, 
            longitude: 20.225282 
        },
        control: {}, 
        zoom: 13,
        options: { 
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
        }
    };
    $scope.zoom = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        //the problem is here.  $scope.map.setZoom() gets undefined.
        $scope.map.setZoom(9);
    };
```

--- adding example

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('MapController', mapController)


mapController.$inject = ['$scope', 'uiGmapIsReady'];

function mapController($scope, uiGmapIsReady) {
  
  $scope.map = { 
    center: { 
      latitude: 67.855800, 
      longitude: 20.225282 
    },
    control: {}, 
    zoom: 13,
    options: { 
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      streetViewControl: false,
      backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2'
    }
  };
  
  $scope.zoom = function($event) {
    $scope.map.control.getGMap().setZoom(9);
  };
        
  uiGmapIsReady
    .promise()
    .then(function (maps) {
      // ready to manip map
    });
};
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            position: relative;
        }

        .angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>



<div ng-app='app' id='map_canvas' ng-controller='MapController'>
  <button ng-click='zoom()'>Set Zoom</button>
  <ui-gmap-google-map 
   center="map.center"
   zoom="map.zoom"
   control="map.control">
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But i get "map.control is undefined".

Comment: I have updated your sample to inject `map.control` it should no longer be undefined when you try and call it

Comment: I implemented the changes and did this:  console.log($scope.map.control); which gets undefined..

Comment: Are you sure, I have added an example and it works as expected -- see the answer

Comment: Ah, thanks man! i owe you one. This could have been a long night.